# Stack Linked List pop() and isEmpty() not working, no idea where the bug is

Tags: c++, function, class, linked-list, stack

I'm working on a project and can't get past a couple bugs. Here's my code.

main()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include "src\DynStack.cpp"
#include "include\DynStack.h"
#include "src\DynQue.cpp"
#include "DynQue.h"
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    ofstream outputFile;

    DynStack<char>cstack;

    inputFile.open("input.txt");

    if (!inputFile)
    {
        cout << "Error. No input file found." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        char x;

        while (!inputFile.eof())
        {
            inputFile.get(x);

            cstack.push(x);

            cout << x;
        }

        inputFile.close();


        outputFile.open("output_reverse.txt");

        char y;

        int count = 1;

        while (cstack.isEmpty() == NULL)
        {
            cstack.pop(y);

            cout << y;

            count++;

        }

        outputFile.close();
    }



    cout << "Program completed." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

DynStack.cpp

```
#include "DynStack.h"
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
DynStack<T>::DynStack()
{
    top = NULL;
}

template<typename T>
void DynStack<T>::push(T val)
{
    StackNode *nodePtr; // ptr to traverse thru the stack
    StackNode *previousNode; // ptr to connect higher node to node below it

    StackNode *newNode;
    newNode = new StackNode; // makes a new StackNode
    newNode->value = val;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (top == NULL) // If the stack is empty
    {
        top = newNode; // Make newNode the first node;
    }
    else
    {
        nodePtr = top; // make our ptr = top

        newNode->next = nodePtr; // make the our new top node, newNode, point to the node below it

        top = newNode; // newNode is our new top of the stack

        delete nodePtr;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void DynStack<T>::pop(T& val)
{
    StackNode *nodePtr; // makes a nodePtr to traverse the stack

    nodePtr = top; // set nodePtr to point to top of stack

    if (top == NULL) // If stack is empty
    {
        cout << "Error. Stack is empty." << endl; // Provide error message.
        return;
    }
    else if (top->next == NULL) // If there is only one item in stack
    {
        val = top->value; // Make return value whatever the previous top was

        delete top; // Delete top

        top = NULL; // make top equal to null
    }
    else // If there is more than one item in stack
    {
            val = top->value; // Return value whatever previous top was

            nodePtr = nodePtr->next; // nodePtr point to node below top node

            delete top; // delete top node

            top = nodePtr; // make nodePtr our new top

            delete nodePtr; // delete the nodePtr
        }
}

template <typename T>
bool DynStack<T>::isEmpty()
{
    if (top == NULL) // If top node is null return true
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (top != NULL) // If top node is not null return false
    {
        return false;
    }
}



template <typename T>
DynStack<T>::~DynStack()
{
    //dtor
}
```

DynStack.h

```
#ifndef DYNSTACK_H
#define DYNSTACK_H

template <typename T>
class DynStack
{
    private:
        struct StackNode
        {
            T value;
            StackNode *next;
        };



    public:
        DynStack();
        ~DynStack();
        void push(T);
        void pop(T&);
        bool isEmpty();

        StackNode *top;
};

#endif // DYNSTACK_H
```

The idea for this program is we take an input file "input.txt" saying "This is the original file." and output it to another text file in reverse. So ".elif lanigiro eht si sihT".

My problems are:

for one, when I run this code, it prints out the while(!inputFile.eof()) just fine. When it runs the second while loop, while(cstack.isEmpty() == NULL), it prints infinitely. I figure there must be something wrong with my pop() or isEmpty() function, but I just don't see what I'm missing. Maybe I'm setting top to NULL wrong in pop(), but I don't see what to change. Maybe there's something wrong with isEmpty(), but that seems so simple I don't know what to add.

More importantly than that though, when I try to run this, the output I get for the second while loop seems to be different everytime. Sometimes it ".e.e.e." repeating. Sometimes its ".el.el.el" repeating. Sometimes it's ".elif.elif.elif" repeating. ".elif.elif.elif" repeating is the closest I've gotten to the correct output, so maybe there's something wrong with outputting or saving whitespace??

I have no idea. If anybody could see what's wrong and explain it to me, I'd be greatly in your debt. Thanks everybody.

Comment: isEmpty is bool why are you comparing it with null?

Comment: There are a ton of problems in this code.  Turn on compiler warnings, and get out your debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is possibly a error on your `push`:

```
template<typename T>
void DynStack<T>::push(T val)
{
    StackNode *nodePtr; // ptr to traverse thru the stack
    StackNode *previousNode; // ptr to connect higher node to node below it

    StackNode *newNode;
    newNode = new StackNode; // makes a new StackNode
    newNode->value = val;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (top == NULL) // If the stack is empty
    {
        top = newNode; // Make newNode the first node;
    }
    else
    {
        nodePtr = top; // make our ptr = top

        newNode->next = nodePtr; // make the our new top node, newNode, point to the node below it

        top = newNode; // newNode is our new top of the stack

        delete nodePtr;
    }
}
```

you are deleting `nodePtr`, which is holding at the moment the value of `top`,a and so you are deleing all the list

Comment: Wow, thank you @Berto99 !! I probably would've found that by trial and error but who knows how long that would've taken. Now that you've said it I can kinda conceptualize why that happens ... I'm still learning how pointers work, they're a bit challenging for me.

Comment: @cstrike2 don't warry all of us are been there once in our live